# What to do (immediately) with a waterlogged pot plant?

Tags: houseplants, watering, compost, repotting

See here for question about what I should do *now*: [What to do (after two weeks) with a waterlogged pot plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/33595/what-to-do-after-two-weeks-with-a-waterlogged-pot-plant)

TL;DR

**What should I have do, immediately, if I suspect that a repotted plant pot is draining poorly?**

---

I recently repotted a bunch of house plants into larger pots, with new compost.

I mixed into the compost some water-retention crystals - the kind that absorb loads of water and can then release that water gradually. I did this because I struggle with under-watering the plants and was hoping that this would result in the dampness of the soil being more stable over time.

**A) If this was a terrible idea from the get-go let me know :)**

Perhaps I mis-judged the amount of crystals, or perhaps it was an error to soak the crystal-enhanced pots like I do for the rest of my plants, but the upshot was that the pots became extremely wet for a long period - I would say waterlogged.

There was water seeping out of the pot into the saucer for 2-3 days (which I would regularly empty), and the surface of the soil was definitely wet to the touch.
I then didn't water the pot for a week and a half, and left the plant outside on a South-East facing balcony for a very hot(23-27 degrees) and sunny week. and by the end of that week and a half, the soil is still not particularly dry (although it is at least not actively WET now).

I perceive that the plants definitely suffered from this - several (though not all) of the leaves very suddenly went extremely pale and then died, other leaves have gained a pale halo around their edge, and for the 3-4 days after I did this, the plants appeared to wilt (as though I'd UNDER-watered them) though it has now recovered

I have multiple questions, so the above set up has been duplicated on multiple posts, but my question here is ...

---

**B) What *should* I have done, that afternoon or the next day, when I realised that the pot was waterlogged?**

Answer (score 1):

No more than what you did already - other than following the procedure in my answer under your other question (what to do after two weeks), which is something you could have chosen to do immediately you realised there was a problem.